# Which is simplest, easy to use for non programmer, cutomizable jquery form validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, plugins

Which is simplest, easy to use for non programmer, customizable jquery form validation plugin ? I don't need ajaxable . i need simple plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question well, you are looking for the plug-in? If so, check this one: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

It is very easy to use and fully customizable.

Comment: +1, used before and found it simple and elegant. Make sure you check out the plugin's home page as well: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/